# Synchronize multiple signals in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to synchronize multiple signals as could be seen on the picture below:

[image]

Here is is the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd  
  
 
data = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
              26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48,
              49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71,
              72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 
              95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112],
        'Run1': [0, 0, 0, 4.5, 4.6, 4.4, 4.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 2.8, 2.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.5, 4.6, 4.4, 4.3,
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 2.8, 2.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.5, 4.6, 4.4, 4.3, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 2.8, 2.4, 2.8, 2.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.5, 4.6, 4.4, 4.3, 4.3, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 2.5, 2.8, 2.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        'Run2': [0, 0, 4.1, 4.5, 4.6, 4.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.4, 2.4, 2.5, 2.8, 3.3, 0, 0, 0, 0,
              4, 4.1, 4.5, 4.6, 4.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 2.6, 2.4, 2.3, 2.5, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.8, 4.4, 4.8, 4.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.4, 2.3, 2.3, 2.1, 2.8, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4.1, 4.5, 4.6, 4.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 2.8, 2.4, 2.8, 2.1],
        'Run3': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.6, 4.4, 4.3, 4.7, 4.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.4, 2.8, 2.1, 0, 0, 0, 4.6, 4.4, 4.3,
              4.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 0, 0, 0, 4.6, 4.4, 4.3, 4.4, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 2.8, 2.4, 2.8, 2.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.5, 4.6, 4.4, 4.3, 4.3, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 2.2, 2.1, 2.5, 2.8, 2.4, 2.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]       
       }  
  

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

The first step would be to move the non-zero value to the top position (index 0) of all columns as it is shown on the picture below:

[image]

Then leave a space of fours rows with zero values:

[image]

then move then move next values>0 to to index under the space with 4 zero-rows etc.

The goal should be a synchronized signals - synchronized on the fisrt non-zeto values as shown on the first picture.

Is there any way, how to do it?
Maybe some library or ..
Any hints are welcome.

Comment: The problem you are tring to solve isn't trivial. You can see, that the signals has little different values. I'm not an expert in Signal Processing, but I would search "middle point" of each "signal peak" and save it in separate "column". Then I would compare  new columns(with appropriete margin) with "middle points" to synchronize request columns.

Comment: If you are familiar with Signal Processing terms, you can search sollution in dedicated Python library, look here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html